# handsontable row height doesnt match when using column freeze

Tags: handsontable

[image: PIC 1]

[image: PIC 2]

when I used column freeze option I had this problem. Row height is okay when the cell only contain single line words like

"Amy should look around for any last items, notice the surfboard and then move to it."

but when the words become like this (have multiple line) the column freeze's row have different height :

"Amy should look around for any last items, notice the

surfboard and then move to it."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I used to have this same problem and I'd wager you're using Bootstrap and have checkboxes in your code. If not, it may not be the same problem.

If it is, then you have to go into the Bootstrap code and remove the css that adds margins to checkboxes. That fixed it for me and should be entered as a bug in the git repo.

Comment: yes I am using bootstrap but there are no checkboxes in my code and actually I have dropdown lists in my code. The column freeze's row have different height about 1 px with the multiple line column unfreezed's row

Comment: yeah i remember the 1 px difference. unfortunately, it got fixed for me when i removed the checkbox css. you can try this: remove the dropdowns (turn them to numeric or something) and see if the problem is still there. If not, look for the css in bootstrap that affects these, then remove it

Comment: I fixed this problem by downgrade the version of handsontable (0.10.5)

Comment: :/ not that great of a solution. There are many great things with the newest versions so I would keep looking for ways to fix it. I'll keep an eye out on git

Comment: I had the same problem with checkboxes, though I'm not using Bootstrap. I wonder if any progress has been made on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent this behaviour by enabling AutoRowSize plugin (autoRowSize: true)

Source: https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/493#issuecomment-155519503

If that does not work on it's own, try using both autoRowSize: true and autoColumnSize: true